# Rails Admin, different interface for has_many relationship other than the default 'tabbed' interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

When dealing with records that have a LOT of a belongs_to relationship, the default 'tabbed' interface is pretty clunky.  Is anyone aware of a plugin that uses a different interface such as a table?

Just thought I'd ask before I go and spend the time making one.

Comment: So I basically just hacked the css to display the hidden tabs the way I wanted.